# Assigning a JFrame to another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, variable-assignment

I am trying to make the current JFrame become a JFrame that is stored in memory. At the moment I am correctly reading the JFrame from memory and I can get it to display but all the action listeners are not working.

```
        gui.dispose();
        gui = savedGUI;
        gui.setVisible(true);
```

This doesn't seem to be properly setting the current GUI (gui) to the saved version (savedGUI). Is there a different method I should be calling on gui rather than setVisible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you doing this? What is the overall purpose, as I'm guessing that there are better ways to do what you're trying to do such as saving the model portion of the GUI rather than the view.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is load a GUI from memory, just as it was when it was saved.

Comment: You would be much better served to save the state of the model of your application and then recreate the GUI based on this state.

Comment: I agree you may be right, but I was wondering if their is a way to reconstruct a stored JFrame object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved when I made sure all the ActionListeners implemented Serializable.

Comment: Why are you serializing a JFrame to memory?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are doing either. Why do you think you need to refer to the GUI with a single reference variable?

Just do:

```
savedGui.setVisible( false );
```

We you want to display the GUI again you do:

```
savedGui.setVisible( true );
```

Comment: Setting the savedGUI as visible displays the GUI but all the action listeners have been removed, which are essential to my program. This person seems to be having the same problem http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.java.gui/Serialization-on-JFrame-action-listener-not-being-restore

Comment: You will not lose the listeners when you make a Gui invisible.